How can I resolve names of a docker-compose services in pods running within a k3s cluster running within the docker-compose?
I am trying to create an environment for demonstrating my application that deploys pods to Kubernetes, so I created a docker compose file:
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      target: final
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - cluster-config:/cluster-config
    depends_on:
      cluster:
        condition: service_healthy
      customer-db-1:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      Modules__Deployment__KubernetesHost : 'https://cluster:6443'
      Modules__Deployment__KubernetesPublicUrl : http://localhost
      Modules__Deployment__KubernetesInternalUrl : http://cluster
      KUBECONFIG : /cluster-config/kubeconfig.yaml

  customer-db-1:
    build: ./src/Images/mssql-example-customer-db/
    # restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: password123!
    ports:
      - 2223:1433
    healthcheck:
      test: cat /usr/src/app/initialized | grep -q Initialized && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P "password123!" -Q "SELECT 1" -b -o /dev/null
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 7
      start_period: 360s
    volumes:
      - customer-db-1:/var/opt/mssql

  cluster:
    build: ./src/Images/ingress-nginx-k3s/
    tmpfs:
    - /run
    - /var/run
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 6443:6443
    ulimits:  
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 65535
        hard: 65535
    privileged: true

    environment:
      # - K3S_TOKEN=${K3S_TOKEN:?err}
      - K3S_KUBECONFIG_OUTPUT=/output/kubeconfig.yaml
      - K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE=644
    volumes:
    - k3s-server:/var/lib/rancher/k3s
    # This is just so that we get the kubeconfig file out
    - cluster-config:/output
    healthcheck:
      test: kubectl get --raw='/readyz' | grep -q 'ok' && kubectl get --raw='/healthz' | grep -q 'ok' && cat /usr/local/bin/initialized | grep -q Initialized
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 130s


volumes:
  cluster-config: {}
  customer-db-1: {}
  k3s-server: {}


The problem is that I cannot connect to the customer-db-1 service from within a pod running in the cluster using the customer-db-1 name (to test that I used kubectl exec -it {pod-name} -- ping customer-db-1 and got ping: bad address 'customer-db-1').
However, if I run docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' customer-db-1-1 and use the ip that the command outputs (172.19.0.3). It works just fine.
Within the server service, I can use the name customer-db-1 just fine. It has to do something with DNS resolution. Does anyone know what should I change to be able to use the names of the docker-compose services within the cluster? Alternatively (if the first option is not possible), can I somehow fix the ip addresses of containers to stay the same?
Edit:
I found out that I can use docker subnets for the alternative case.

If your application should be running in Kubernetes, why did you write a Docker Compose file?  Can you rewrite this as a StatefulSet for your database, a ConfigMap for your application configuration, a Deployment for the application proper, and Services to match, all in native Kubernetes configuration?

@DavidMaze I want anyone to be able to run it locally without the need of installing kubernetes, it is sort of a development environment.

Kubernetes isn't really suitable for a development environment.  Can you run the entire setup in Compose; or better still, run the database via Compose, and run the application in local tools?  (Why does Kubernetes need to be part of the development setup?  Why does Docker?)

@DavidMaze The point of the project is to be a SaaS platform, so the server communicates with the cluster using KubernetesClient and deploys instances of other applications on user request. The instances are separated by URL path prefix so that's why I use Ingress Nginx with the K3s.

That sounds like Kubernetes is a required part of the application.  That's fine, if that's your design point.  If needing both Docker (Desktop?) and Kubernetes is an obstacle, consider a VM-based setup like Minikube.  A plain-Docker (or Compose) environment will always be separate from Kubernetes, though, and a container in one environment can't generally communicate with a container in the other.

If you want to deploy your app in kubernetes, every instance will be a pod in kuberentes. So when you want to connect for example to your database you have to call its service name in kuberentes
